# HTML5 geolocation with highaccuracy and watchposition

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to figure out how to add high accuracy and watchposition to html5 geolocation. I want the gps to update with the user moving. Can anyone help?

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                marker.setPosition(latlng);
                map.setCenter(latlng);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `watchPosition` method.

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(updatePosition);

function updatePosition(pos){
   console.log(pos.coords);
}
```

As for accuracy, the `watchPosition` method accepts 3 parameters (success, error and options) of which the last two are optional.
The above sample shows use of the success callback, now if you add another two..

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
     updatePosition,
     // Optional settings below
     positionError,
     {
         timeout: 0,
         enableHighAccuracy: true,
         maximumAge: 0
     }
);
```

The options enables `enableHighAccuracy` which is self explanatory.

References:

[Html5 GeoLocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition)

[Position Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions)

Comment: thank you but how to enable high accuracy in my code??